# How can I get all the triggers linked to a specific table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm searching for a way to retrieve all the triggers where there is an action linked to a specific table.
I don't want to read manually all the triggers I have on the server as there are too many.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *an action linked to a specific table*? Do you want to find triggers that listen to changes of a certain table, or triggers on other tables, that modify some table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TRIGGERS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE';
```

Comment: You might want to use `ALL_TRIGGERS` instead of `USER_TRIGGERS` if you are interested in schemas others than your own.

Comment: Using DBA_TRIGGERS instead of USER_TRIGGERS worked for me. ALL_TRIGGERS describes owned by the current user and triggers on tables owned by the current user. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2107.htm#i1592586

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what Peter Lang indicated then look into the view dba_dependencies (or all_dependencies or user_dependencies of course).